# How to use multiple columns as a single key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas data frame that looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I need to sum the values for which I need to treat the A, B and C columns as a key, but I don't know how. The end product should look like this

| Column A | Column B | Column C | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 13 |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 11 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 10 |

I tried to use Groupby, but it didn't turn out to be what I expected it to be.

Comment: You need to sum column A, B and C?

Comment: Maybe: `df.groupby(['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C']).sum()`?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(SUM=('VALUE','sum'))`

Comment: Please post your attempted trial. Pandas' group by aggregation is an often asked and answered question. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) before asking.